# How to zoom canvas view and image view at a time in android

Tags: android, canvas, imageview

I am developing one application. In that am adding two views one above another. Below one is image view
and above is canvas view. Am displaying two bitmaps one is in image view below and one bitmap is in canvas view above. Am adding erase functionality to above canvas view. I want to display when am click a button erasing will be stopped and add zoom functionality two views above and below, when am touch for zoom it will be zoom two views at a time. Am trying this but am getting only one view will be zooming How can i do this please help me..

```
class:



public class ImageClass extends Activity{

public static ImageView img,imgbg,i1,i2,i3,i4,i5,i6,save,radius,zoomimg;
int screenWidth, screenHeight;
RelativeLayout relative,rrr,mainrel,relpop;
Panel p;
Button clkk,popupp;

Bitmap bitmap;

int x = 0;
int y =0;
float r =20;
float xend;
float yend;
int pos;
FrameLayout fff;
View v;

AttributeSet attrs;
/*private ArrayList<Path> undonePaths = new ArrayList<Path>();
private ArrayList<Path> paths = new ArrayList<Path>();*/
int slll = Color.BLACK;
public static File mediaFile;
File sdfolder,f;
Canvas pcanvas;
int aa,bb;
public static Bitmap blkwhtbtp,belowbtp,abovebtp;


@SuppressLint({ "CutPasteId", "ShowToast" })
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.image);

    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    screenWidth = metrics.widthPixels;
    screenHeight = metrics.heightPixels;

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Touch to unblur image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    relative=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.rrlayout);
    rrr=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relativebg);
    mainrel=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.main);

    imgbg=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    p=new Panel(this);

    relative.addView(p);

    belowbtp=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Utils.imageBitmap, screenWidth, screenHeight, true);
    imgbg.setImageBitmap(belowbtp);


    radiuslayout=new LinearLayout(this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams radiusparams=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(screenWidth/2,screenHeight/10);
    radiusparams.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
    radiuslayout.setLayoutParams(radiusparams);
    radiuslayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

    radius = new ImageView(this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams pp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    pp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    radius.setLayoutParams(pp);
    radius.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);


    radius.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @SuppressLint({ "ShowToast", "WrongCall" })
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "radius", 1000).show();
            p.mPaint.setXfermode(null);

            imgbg.setOnTouchListener(new Touchhimage());

            p.detector = new ScaleGestureDetector(getApplicationContext(), p.new ScaleListener());




         }
         });


         class Panel extends View {

    private Path    mPath;
    private Paint   mPaint;
    //Context context;
    private ArrayList<Path> paths = new ArrayList<Path>();
    private ArrayList<Path> undonePaths = new ArrayList<Path>(); 
    public int selectedcolor;
    private static final float MIN_ZOOM = 1f;
    private static final float MAX_ZOOM = 5f;
    private float scaleFactor = 1.f;
    private ScaleGestureDetector detector;

    ///
    private static final int NONE = 0;
    private static final int DRAG = 1;
    private static final int ZOOM = 2;

    private int mode;

    private float startX = 0f;
    private float startY = 0f;

    private float translateX = 0f;
    private float translateY = 0f;

    private float previousTranslateX = 0f;
    private float previousTranslateY = 0f;  

    boolean dragged;


    MotionEvent ev;

    @SuppressLint({ "InlinedApi", "NewApi", "ShowToast" })
    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    public Panel(Context context) {
        super(context);

        Log.v("Panel", ">>>>>>");

        setFocusable(true);
        setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setAlpha(0);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setDither(true);
        mPath = new Path();


        Bitmap bm=Utils.imageBitmap;
        abovebtp=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm, screenWidth, screenHeight, true);
        // Bitmap bm=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.test);
        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(screenWidth, screenHeight, Config.ARGB_8888);
        pcanvas = new Canvas();
        pcanvas.setBitmap(bitmap);

        detector = new ScaleGestureDetector(getContext(), new ScaleListener());



        @Override
      public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasWindowFocus) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasWindowFocus);
        abovebtp=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Utils.imageBitmap, imgbg.getWidth(), imgbg.getHeight(), true);

        blkwhtbtp=Blur.fastblur(getApplicationContext(), abovebtp, 24);

        pcanvas.drawBitmap(blkwhtbtp, 0, 0, null);



        }



        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {  

        // draw a circle that is  erasing bitmap 

        canvas.scale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor);

         if((translateX * -1) < 0) {
               translateX = 0;
            }

         else if((translateX * -1) > (scaleFactor - 1) * screenWidth) {
               translateX = (1 - scaleFactor) * screenWidth;
            }

            if(translateY * -1 < 0) {
               translateY = 0;
            }

            else if((translateY * -1) > (scaleFactor - 1) * screenHeight) {
                translateY = (1 - scaleFactor) * screenHeight;
             }

            canvas.translate(translateX / scaleFactor, translateY / scaleFactor);

        //pcanvas.drawBitmap(blkwhtbtp, 0, 0, mPaint);
        if (bitmap!=null) {
            canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0,null);
        }


        for (Path p : paths){
            pcanvas.drawPath(p, mPaint);
        }


        pcanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
        pcanvas.drawCircle(x, y, r, mPaint);    
        pcanvas.save();


        super.onDraw(canvas);
       } 




       private float mX, mY;
       private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;
       private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
        // undonePaths.clear();
        mPath.reset();
        mPath.moveTo(x, y);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
       }
      private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
        float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
        float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
        if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
            mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX)/2, (y + mY)/2);
            mX = x;
            mY = y;
        }
       }
      private void touch_up() {
        mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
        // commit the path to our offscreen
        pcanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);

        // kill this so we don't double draw
        paths.add(mPath);


       }





        @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        //ev=event;
        detector.onTouchEvent(event);
        //mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        x = (int) event.getX();
        y = (int) event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:



            touch_start(x, y);

              mode = DRAG;
             startX = event.getX() - previousTranslateX;
             startY = event.getY() - previousTranslateY;



                        invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "testing", 1000).show();

             mode = NONE;
             dragged = false;

             previousTranslateX = translateX;
             previousTranslateY = translateY;

            invalidate();
            break;

         case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
         touch_move(x, y);

             translateX = event.getX() - startX;
                translateY = event.getY() - startY;

                double distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(event.getX() - (startX + previousTranslateX), 2) + 
                        Math.pow(event.getY() - (startY + previousTranslateY), 2)
                        );

                if(distance > 0) {
                    dragged = true;
                 } 


                invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:

            x = (int) event.getX();
            y = (int) event.getY();

            mPath.lineTo(x, y);

             mode = DRAG;

             previousTranslateX = translateX;
             previousTranslateY = translateY;



            invalidate();

            break;
           }

         if ((mode == DRAG && scaleFactor != 1f && dragged) || mode == ZOOM) {
                invalidate();
            }

        return true;

        }


      public class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
        @Override

         public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {

            scaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();

            scaleFactor = Math.max(MIN_ZOOM, Math.min(scaleFactor, MAX_ZOOM));

            invalidate();

            return true;

            }

            }




  xml:


  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/linear" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativebg"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"

       >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" 

            android:scaleType="matrix"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rrlayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       >


    </RelativeLayout> 



  </RelativeLayout>


    <LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/linear"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"

    >

   </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You should scale your image bitmap and canvas like this according to your need.

myBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(myBitmap
,(int)(myBitmap.getWidth()*1.3f), (int)(myBitmap.getWidth()*1.3f), true);
and your canvas

mCanvas.scale(1.3f, 1.3f);

Comment: Thank you for your reply but how can i zoom canvas view and image view at a time.

Comment: Post your code. what you are doing to zoom?

Comment: am post my code see once..

Comment: which view you can’t zoom?

Comment: individually image view(imgbg in coding) and canvas view(panel p) zooming working but i want to zoom two views image view and canvas view at a time. two views will be zoom on radius onclick in above coding

Comment: in your radius onClick
add this:
belowbtp=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(belowbtp
, (int)(belowbtp.getWidth()*scaleFactor)
, (int)(belowbtp.getHeight()*scaleFactor)
, true);

Comment: thank you for your code but it is not working. Tell me the correct solution please.

Comment: can i have xml file here?

Comment: am post xml see once and tell me please..

Comment: please can u tell me the solution how can do this.